# Trying to get the first record for each MemID in this LINQ Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a LINQ query, which is working, as below.  The only problem is that sometimes I get repeating MEMIds. **How can I get only the first MemID from this query *in a single database trip*?**
I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 as my backend database, and C# as the programming language.

```
var query = (from m in e.Memberships
             where m.MEMID != null 
                  && (SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.MEMID).Contains(memIdOrName) 
                        || m.NAME.Contains(memIdOrName))  
             select new { 
                             m.MEMID, 
                             NAME = m.NAME.TrimEnd(), 
                             m.CITY, 
                             m.STATE, 
                             m.SYSTEMID, 
                             SYSTEMNAME = m.SYSTEMNAME.TrimEnd() 
                        })
                        .Distinct()
                        .OrderBy(s => s.NAME)
                        .ThenBy(s => s.CompanyID)
                        .ThenBy(s => s.CITY)
                        .ThenBy(s => s.MEMID);

var a = query.Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group on that value and then select out just one item from that group.  If you don't care which, you can just grab the first.  If you want a particular one, then you can re-order them before taking the first item.

So replace `Distinct` with;

```
//everything before `Distinct`
.GroupBy(s => s.MEMID)
.Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault())//or some other query to get one item in the group
//rest of your query
```

Comment: Ok. I will try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the underlying query provider, it's likely you'll need to use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.First()`

Comment: This works. BUT the performance is very poor now. Before it was fast and almost instant.

Comment: @Sunil Well, it's doing something radically different.  How fast something executes is irrelevant if it doesn't actually *work*.

Comment: @Sevy, Yes that's true. One question:  is the query doing the grouping on database side or on code-side?

Comment: @Sunil I'm not sure whether the query provider can translate this or not.  You're best bet is to look at the log and see for yourself.